# How do I dynamically chain a function in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-7

In my Laravel Scheduler

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{

    if(env('APP_DEBUG') == true){
        $cronInterval = 'everyMinute()';
    } else {
        $cronInterval = 'daily()';
    }


    $schedule->command('inspire')
            ->$cronInterval
            ->emailOutputTo(env('MAIL_TO')); // tried
```

How do I dynamically chain a function in Laravel ?

[image]

Comment: Please suggest a sample code base on your comment, I will try now.

Comment: Notice how it's saying **`Undefined property`**? It's thinking that `everyMinute()` and `daily()` are properties, not methods. I think the answer below, omitting the `()` from the string and appending like `->{$cronInterval}()` should solve your issue :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called [variable functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php). Try this:

```
$cronInterval = env('APP_DEBUG') ? 'everyMinute' : 'daily';

$schedule->command('inspire')
    ->{$cronInterval}()
    ->emailOutputTo(env('MAIL_TO'));
```